# Add/remove a class in html using a js function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a class to body in HTML using Javascript using a button that executes a function, then remove it using another button. But I want to save that class, until the other button is pressed, using LocalStorage.
I can do that without LocalStorage

```
$$('body').addClass('Class here');
```

But how with LocalStorage?

Answer (score 1):

By using [`Storage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) to save, then [`Storage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to retrieve, like this:

```
var className = "theclass";

// Put the class name into storage
localStorage.setItem('className', className);

// Retrieve the class name from storage
var retrievedClassName = localStorage.getItem('className');

$('body').addClass(retrievedClassName);
```

Comment: What do I put into both functions?

Comment: setItem(key,value), getItem(key)

Answer (score 0):

Here a working code with jquery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="button">your button</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var className = "theclass";

            jQuery('.button').on( 'click', function(){
                localStorage.setItem('className', className);
                jQuery('body').addClass(className);
            });

            // Retrieve the class name from storage
            var retrievedClassName = localStorage.getItem('className');
            jQuery('body').addClass(retrievedClassName);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here without:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body id="mybigbody" class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="button">your button</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var className = "theclass";
            var body = document.getElementById("mybigbody");

            document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(e) {
                localStorage.setItem('className', className);
                body.setAttribute("class", className);
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            // Retrieve the class name from storage
            var retrievedClassName = localStorage.getItem('className');
            if(retrievedClassName)
                body.setAttribute("class", retrievedClassName);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not using Jquery

Comment: @jekeajames So tell to me what is the $$? I thinked was a jquery typo.

Comment: Anyway the problem is the same. Inside your click event you can set the classname on your localstorage and on your body. And outside, at start you must retrive your class with getItem  and the attach it on body.

Comment: How, by adding getItem to the body? Sorry but I am new to JS

Comment: @jekeajames with `var retrievedClassName = localStorage.getItem('className');` you can get from your local storage the class that you have saved with click in some precedent moment. So on retrievedClassName you have your class name. Now you must attach it to your body. Whit javascript without andy library you can do `var body = document.getElementById("body"); body.setAttribute("class", retrievedClassName);`

Comment: @jakeajames now you can see another working example without jquery but only wit javascript

Comment: I putted that line on the js file, and still doesn't work. So?

Comment: @jakeajames I have edited the last example 2 times in few minutes and i have tested it on my pc. If you don't paste me some error ore some more information i can't help you more than now.

Comment: The script doesn't even change the class

Comment: @jakeajames the script change the class 2 different moment and situation. the page loaded the first time doesn't have any class. When yuo click on the button it set the class to the body and inside localstorage. This is the first situation. Then if you refresh the page it will add the class saved on the early visit without anyclick

Comment: Does this work on any browser? Does it work on Apple Safari (iPhone)?

Comment: I think the problem is that I putted the button on a page that is parsed with the main page. I want to add the class on the main page, so I think it adds the class to the second.

Comment: @jekeajames i have tested it on Chromium 52.0.2743.116. I have not an apple to test it. But this function are standard.

Comment: Read the last comment, this may be the problem

Comment: @jakeajames i can't image what i don't see. My code it's enought to understand how it work. If you pay attention it add the class at the element that have the `id="mybigbody"` so you need to put it in the element that you need.

Comment: It works if I put the button on the main page and not on the one parsed with it

Comment: @jakeajames So.. better question explanation, better and fast solution.

Comment: But I want it on the Ajax-parsed one